# Why the time needed for executing code on "Hackerrank" site varies significantly?

Tags: performance, server, computer-science, benchmarking, cpu-architecture

When you try some coding challenges on www.hackerrank.com and you track the time also (e.g. in C++ using the "chrono" library), you will see every time you run the Code you will get a different time needed for execution at exactly the same Code. The variance I estimate at 10 to 30 percent. What is the reason that Code execution times are varying significantly at equal code? Which factors account to it?

It could be the Server System; but are there even physical reasons (stochastic processes in electronic components)?

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly just a busy system where your process competes for CPU time against other processes.  (And competes for memory bandwidth even when it has a CPU to itself).

---

Also it's likely that the server runs on a CPU with [SMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_multithreading) (Simultaneous multithreading) that uses each physical cores as two logical cores, so the "shared execution resources" that processes compete for includes stuff inside a single CPU core, not just L3 cache and memory bandwidth.

Intel calls their SMT tech "[hyperthreading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading)"; most servers these days run on Intel Xeon CPUs.  AMD Zen also uses SMT, so either way unless the server admins disabled it, when the OS schedules tasks onto both logical cores of a single physical core, they will slow each other down some (with the slowdown amount mostly depending on their average IPC (instructions per cycle) - two threads that have a lot of branch mispredicts will typically not see much slowdown (so throughput nearly doubles).  But two threads that could both nearly saturate the FP multiplier ALUs on their own will each run at nearly half speed (near zero gain in throughput).

OSes "know about" SMT / Hyperthreading and can detect which logical cores share a physical core.  They try to avoid scheduling threads to the same physical core while there are some physical cores with both threads idle.

See also [Modern Microprocessors
A 90-Minute Guide!](http://www.lighterra.com/papers/modernmicroprocessors/) which covers SMT, with the background to understand what execution resources are being shared.

---

> but are there even physical reasons (stochastic processes in electronic components)?

No, CPUs are deterministic (except for the `rdrand` instruction which uses true analog electrical noise as a randomness source).

CPUs do use dynamic voltage and frequency scaling to save power (idle vs. max turbo, or somewhere in between if thermal limits don't allow max turbo.)    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_frequency_scaling

**See also [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation) for more microbenchmarking pitfalls / warm-up effects.**